# Unexpected token < in Angular2 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, angular-cli

I have built an Angular2 app that works great locally on both my work and home computers but fails when I try pushing it to Azure!

All of the 4 .js files that are produced from `ng build -prod` command (inline, main, polyfills and vendor) report a error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I click through the highlighted line is always in my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I presume that this is either a bug in the latest version of CLI or a dependency issue but I don't know where to start as I can't replicate it locally, even with `ng serve -prod`

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "budget.front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6",
    "angular2-jwt":"~0.1.28",
    "auth0-js": "^8.3.0",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.12.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and my system is:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
node: 6.9.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

**Update with index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Budget </title>
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/ice-cream.png">


<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.12.3/lock.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**dist\index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Budget </title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/ice-cream.png">


<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.12.3/lock.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="styles.bd88389e6ebba2f4c82b.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.176eda039efb277d0b1a.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.f52c146b4f7d1751829e.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.02550e5852673137ddc8.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d7e4099a93c3c9dc1bf6.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This is my first app with Angular and I just keep running into brick walls with one thing or the other!

**Web.config file, added to resolve angular routing as per another issue**

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <clear />

        <!-- ignore static files -->
        <rule name="AngularJS Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(app/.*|css/.*|fonts/.*|images/.*|js/.*|node_modules/.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="None" />
        </rule>

        <!-- check if its root url and navigate to default page -->
        <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/home" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>

        <!--remaining all other url's point to index.html file -->
        <rule name="AngularJS Wildcard" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>

        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please share the index.html code too

Comment: Just added, meant to include that!

Comment: Is this the post-`ng build` (dist) index.html file?  (Looks like this is your src -- cli modifies your index.html during `ng build` to include the app dependencies.)

Comment: Try to replace your prod build node_modules folder with your local. I experienced that some subdependenciesbwere not installed properly.

Comment: @SteveG. good point, question updated thanks

Comment: @SteveG. I think its serving the index.html, I get the "loading app" message but it hits the javascript error and it fails. I've added a screen grab of the console if it helps?

Comment: You probably messed up your server and requests for bundle.js are instead serving the 404 or an error message, that probably starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` (hence the unexpected `<`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with your URL rewrite section of your `web.config`.  It's serving those files back as your index.html page.

Try replacing your rewrite section with something similar to this to test the thoery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This basically uses a RegEx to route all requests back to index.html (or root, if you prefer), except for the static resources that I'm using (.js, .css, .png, etc.)

**Side-Note**: If you're also hosting a .Net app on this same domain, you may want to modify your .Net application's route config or deep linking to your angular app isn't going to work.

You have a few options, although since I don't know your requirements, I can't recommend one over the other.  You could:

If the .Net app is not needed:

1. Remove the .Net app entirely and just host static files on your Azure site, or:
2. Modify your Azure site app's [.Net] route config to redirect all controller requests to your home controller. (Not really your best option, IMO.)

Comment: Hi, I tried this code but I get a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." so progress!

Comment: The deployment is successful though, so I guess more of a run time error now ?

Comment: No, well not that I am aware of, the back end of this app is on a different url BackEndApp.Azure rather than the FrontendApp.Azure. Is there anywhere else I can look to rule that out?

Comment: This is the error I get in Azure:

This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't have the rep!

Comment: Yeah just a basic default Web App. Looking at the console in the portal, it looks to be the same set of files as per my Angular project

Comment: @ChrisA So it looks like your site is down again.  It appeared to be working for a bit a while ago and I was able to see your Angular app.  Did something else change?

Comment: Ah yes, I think I missed one of the deployments but you caught it up! I basically removed the top rule in my web.config, and then replaced the whole thing with the code you suggested which didn't work

Comment: @ChrisA No problem!  Glad that I could help.  Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 2):

This is due the creation of project directory inside the dist folder which is not being pointed by your index.html file.
Fixed it by changing the base tag from `<base href="/">`to `<base href="/project-app/">` inside index.html file.