# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - MEAN stack with angular2-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, mean.io

Angular2 application is working well already.I have been trying to implement MEAN stack with that angular2 application by adding server.js but I ain't sure why i don't find index.html webpage not appearing in browser.
My folder structure is: 
[image]

And express.js is:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.use('/src',express.static(__dirname+'/src'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/src/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

The path is all right but in browser, 
[image].

I even tried with ng build to obtain dist folder and tried pointing to dist/index.html but it didn't work as well.Please favour.

Edit:
index.html -src

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Something</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

index.html - dist

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Something</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in browser console ?

Comment: After ngbuild and pointing to index.html of dist folder, i get   localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/inline.bundle.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/styles.bundle.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: do this `ng build --base-href . ` and then try

Comment: when i change <app-root></app-root> to <p>i am here</p>, i am able to view "i am here" in browser. So, problem is with loading the component. So fishy!

Comment: yes, the JS are not loaded u are getting 404, thats why i said do this command `ng build--base-href .`

Comment: the same persist

Comment: still the same 404's ?? check your index.html & See does it have base href= . ???

Comment: <base href="/">

Comment: it should be <base href=".">, use command `ng build --base-href .`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    ( for all js )

Comment: thats because your express script is wrong, it points to index.html for everything. please see my answer. !

Answer (score 3):

you get unexpected token error because the express script is wrong. for each request it is serving index.html & Hence the `error unexpected token <`

Use this express script.

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`))
```

Steps :

1. do `ng build --base-href .`
2. start express or server script.

base href . is important otherwise you will get 404 for JS & Resources.

Edit :
[image]

Comment: I tried it, i get unexpected token < for all js references in dist/index.html

Comment: you used this express script  ??? cause i just now checked & it worked perfectly fine for me .!

Comment: strange.. 
can u ensure 
1. server.js is parallel to the dist folder.
2. the express script is same as the answer i posted.
3. open index.html & Copy the JS paths .. i.e something like `script src=`

Comment: i have added index.html of src and dist. Doing ng build --base-href . didn't work as well.!

Comment: my situation is now same as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819588/unexpected-token-in-angular2-cli. i ain't sure what is that web.config

Comment: web.config is of .net and is unrelated to node js ! seeing your dist/index.html it doesn't contain `base href .` , thats why you are getting the issue still. see my screenshot.! try changing base href manually or run `ng build --base-href .`  command properly

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the creation of project directory inside the dist folder which is not being pointed by your index.html file. Fixed it by changing the base tag from  `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/project-app/">` inside index.html file.

note: in your case project-app would be the folder inside the dist directory

Answer (score 1):

I find the tutorial below in setting up mean with Angular 2 and it's how I set up my app.

2:https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

You may to modify the following code in that tutorial:

```
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/node-angular');    

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

I hope it works out for you.

Comment: when i change <app-root></app-root> to <p>i am here</p>, i am able to view "i am here" in browser. So, problem is with loading the component.

Comment: I am just trying to help you and this is what I have in index.html  <base href="#">

Comment: If you follow the tutorial(link I provide), your app should work. Have a nice day.

Comment: i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  for all bundle.js

Comment: I have it as reference from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your **dist** folder into a **views** folder and set your public path in server like bellow:

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));





app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.use(express.static('views/dist'));
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('dist/index.html')
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('port opened');
})
```

here's my folder tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in the header of your `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)